# About hydra, crunch and 7-zip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want to create a password list using crunch. As you know the file will become more than 1 petabyte. I know that in 7-zip you can "archive" a file in the format of "7z" and compress it by a lot. If I create a text file then compress it to a "7z" format, then is it possible to get crunch to access the text file while it is compressed in the "7z" format and to add to the list.

Also is it possible to get hydra to read an archive in this format "7z", when you want to use a password list?